# What does header("location: file_name.php?fail=2") mean?

Tags: php, redirect, header

Generally speaking, I know it is used to force redirect after an action is performed (like when we request a PHP script to write into the database).

But I was wondering what the `?fail=2` does and what other options are there besides it. Also, can the header be used in several PHP scripts that do different tasks but all must redirect to same page?

Are there other ways to **automatically** redirect to that page besides using the header?

Comment: It only means what the `file_name.php` script interprets it as - it is just a key-value pair (key=`fail`, value=`2`). You can do redirects using `<meta>` tags and with JavaScript, but a `Location` is generally best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I was wondering what the ?fail=2 does and what other options are there besides it.

You'd have to look at the code for `file_name.php` to see what the `$_GET['fail']` parameter does. It's just a query string parameter, it can be used to do anything the programmer wanted it to trigger.

As an educated guess, I'd bet `fail=2` tells the script to display a specific error message to the user's browser. `fail=1` probably shows a different error message.

> Are there other ways to automatically redirect to that page besides using the header?

You can use JavaScript or `<meta>` tags to redirect. The `header()` approach is generally better as it's understood by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

`?fail=2` (query string) means sending query string to URL.

```
fail = query string variable
2 = it's value
```

you can use GET method to get it like

```
echo $_GET['fail']; //2
```

Comment: @halfer Suspect that's a typo of `it's`.